# react-map-gl Style Uncaught Error: Style is not done loading

Tags: reactjs, react-map-gl

I am using React-MAP-GL, and I the problem ***Style is not done loading***, when trying to update the `mapStyle` object.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactMapGL from 'react-map-gl';
import {defaultMapStyle, dataLayer} from './map-style.js';

import {fromJS} from 'immutable';
import geoJson from './cali.json';

export default class Map extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      mapStyle: defaultMapStyle,
      data: null,
      viewport: {
        width: 600,
        height: 800,
        latitude: 36.7783,
        longitude: -119.4179,
        zoom: 5,
      },
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this._resize);
    this._loadData(geoJson);
  }


  _loadData = data => {
    const mapStyle = defaultMapStyle
      .setIn(['sources', 'incomeByState'], fromJS({type: 'geojson', data}))
      .set('layers', defaultMapStyle.get('layers').push(dataLayer));

    this.setState({data, mapStyle});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactMapGL
          {...this.state.viewport}
          mapStyle={this.state.mapStyle}
          onViewportChange={viewport => {
            this.setState({viewport});
          }}
          mapboxApiAccessToken=""
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example on react-map-gl didn't work for me, and this is what they did. I think their method is working only because `requestJson` has `this._loadData` on a callback, but I am preloading the `geojson`.

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this._resize);
    this._resize();

    requestJson('data/us-income.geojson', (error, response) => {
      if (!error) {
        this._loadData(response);
      }
    });
  }
```

But I did found a few ways of fixing it:

Option #1:

`setTimeout(() => this._loadData(geoJson), 1);` Even 1 milli-second solves the problem with original approach.

Option #2:
Do not load the data using `ComponentDidMount`, just put a `onClick`, or 'onScroll' event somewhere else to load the data. Kind of hacky...

Option #3:
Use `onLoad`! For some reason, I did not find this method in the first place...

```
<MapGL
          ref={map => (this.mapRef = map)}
          {...this.state.viewport}
          mapStyle={this.state.mapStyle}
          onLoad={() => this._loadData(geoJson)}
          onViewportChange={viewport => {
            this.setState({viewport});
          }}
          mapboxApiAccessToken="8jiOnPbYA"
        />
```